# Formatting a decimal number similar to ToString("G29") plus a thousands separator

Tags: c#, formatting, number-formatting

I need to display some numbers in a variable of type decimal.

I want to display them almost as they are, which `ToString("G29")` gives me.

However, I want to add a thousands separator.  `ToString("N")` gives me the thousands separator but totally loses the "G29 goodness".

Is there a simple solution to get the display string I want?

```
   value         "N"        "G29"      What I Want  
============= ==========  ==========  ==============
296018.413    296,018.41  296018.413   296,018.413   
652609        652,609.00  652609       652,609       
296.018413    296.02      296.018413   296.018413
326.305       326.31      326.305      326.305
```

**Edit:**

Another SO question/answer recently made me aware that "G29" returns values less than 0.0001 in scientific notation.  So when I wrote the question I was unaware that the solution needed to handle special cases like these:

```
  value        What I Want  
============  =============
0.00001       0.00001
12345.000067  12,345.000067
```

Comment: Does [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty simple solution to this, though it involves a fairly long format string.

```
decimal d = 12345.000067m;
string s = d.ToString("#,###0.############################"); // 28 #'s after the decimal
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have to do a little bit of work around.
How about this?

```
decimal d = 34561.2223400M;
string decimalPart = (d - (int)d).ToString("G29");
string integerPart = d.ToString("##,###");
string finalNumber = integerPart + decimalPart.Substring(1,decimalPart.Length-1);;
```

Comment: This answer is very close, but because "G29" returns scientific notation with numbers below 0.0001, it fails with something like 12.0000123 (for which it returns "12.23E-05").

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the string.

Try:

```
string yourString = String.Format("{0:N29}", yourWeight);
```

**Edit:**

The above was pretty close.  This gives exactly the desired results:

```
string yourString = String.Format("{0:N29}", yourWeight).Trim(new [] { '0', '.' });
```

Comment: That's close, but it keeps all the trailing zeroes.  For example, 296,018.41300000000000000000000000000.  Maybe I'll use your solution and trim off the zeros.  That'll be simpler than adding in the commas.

Comment: The second suggestion will not work for values like: `1000` or `1000.00`.

Comment: Oh dear!  Ahmed is correct!  The above will turn [420] into [42]!  I will change the accepted answer.

Comment: `string.Format("{0:N29}", yourWeight).TrimEnd(new[] { '0' }).TrimEnd(new[] { '.' })` works correctly though, doesn't it?